# How to handle multiple return from python as multiple parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

I am working on a project and I am using the eel python library to create GUI. I am using sqlite to store the database. I want to retrieve information and show it in different `<input = text>` input boxes.

**But my output is**
[![It means I am getting all the output in one box][1]][1]

It means I am getting all the output in one box

**My JavaScript code**

```
function set_retrieve_2(name)
{
    document.getElementById("Name").value = name;
    document.getElementById("DOB").value = dob;
    document.getElementById("Sex").value = sex;
    document.getElementById("Address").value = address;
    document.getElementById("phone").value = phone;
    document.getElementById("Of_name").value = of_name;
    document.getElementById("Mem_Number").value = mem_number;
    document.getElementById("Mem_Date").value = mem_date;
}
```

**My python code is**

```
@eel.expose
def retrieved_2(nic):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("information_database")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
    found = c.fetchone()
    if found:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT NIC FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        nic_n = c.fetchone()
        print(nic_n)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT name FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        name = c.fetchone()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT DOB FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        dob = c.fetchone()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT sex FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        sex = c.fetchone()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT address FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        address = c.fetchone()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT phone FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        phone = c.fetchone()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT of_name FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        of_name = c.fetchone()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT mem_number FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        mem_number = c.fetchone()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT mem_date FROM info WHERE NIC= ?", [nic])
        mem_date = c.fetchone()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return name, dob, sex, address, phone, of_name, mem_number, mem_date
```

Please help me thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcFwk.png

Answer (score 1):

Make the python function returns a dictionary/JSON object, which carries the results you want, so change

```
return name, dob, sex, address, phone, of_name, mem_number, mem_date
```

to

```
return { 'name' : name, 'dob' : dob, 'sex' : sex, 'address' : address, 'phone' : phone, 'of_name' : of_name, 'mem_number' : mem_number, 'mem_date' : mem_date }
```

and change the javascript code to

```
async function set_retrieve_2(name)
{
    var data=await eel.retrieved_2(name)();

    document.getElementById("Name").value = data.name;
    document.getElementById("DOB").value = data.dob;
    document.getElementById("Sex").value = data.sex;
    document.getElementById("Address").value = data.address;
    document.getElementById("phone").value = data.phone;
    document.getElementById("Of_name").value = data.of_name;
    document.getElementById("Mem_Number").value = data.mem_number;
    document.getElementById("Mem_Date").value = data.mem_date;
}
```

more clarifications and discussions would be upon comments.